# django1.8 to have regular expression for url in url.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send current url to my view in order to be redirected back to the the original page I started from

I am sending 2 parameters the "pk" and this is key number I use for my operation and "uri"  this is my current url

below line from my url.py I cant figure out how should be set up

```
url(r'^subcategory/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(<uri>\s+)/$',item.views.subcategory_new, name="subcategory_new"),
```

Error message I am getting

```
Reverse for 'subcategory_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 2, u'uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/?name=M_Textile&keywords=&author=&creation_time='}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['item/subcategory/new/(?P<pk>\\d+)/(<uri>\\s+)/$']
```

What I am doing wrong  in my url regular expressions?

And below rest of my code

link from my template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'subcategory_new' pk=category.id uri=request.build_absolute_uri %}">Add SubCategory</a>
```

and finally my view.py

```
@login_required
def subcategory_new(request,pk,uri):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubCategoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subcategory = form.save(commit=False)
            #contact.author = request.user
            subcategory.creation_time = timezone.now()
            subcategory.category = category
            subcategory.save()
            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = SubCategoryForm()
    return render(request, 'item/subcategory_edit.html', {'form': form, 'category':category })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the named capturing group for the `uri`:

```
url(r'^subcategory/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$',item.views.subcategory_new, name="subcategory_new"),
```

And, I've also replaced `\s+` with `\S+` since I doubt you actuall want to capture one or more space characters.